# Creating a bijection between Dyck paths and 231-avoiding permutations

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, catalan-numbers

As a background, 231-avoiding permutations are well described [here.](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PermutationPattern.html)

I have done some reading and found [this](https://ac.els-cdn.com/S019688580190747X/1-s2.0-S019688580190747X-main.pdf?_tid=299a1646-d98b-11e7-96e6-00000aacb35d&acdnat=1512457927_7d4c93ec4d7b151efc6c3adcce439926) paper but I don't really understand the argument. I was wondering if anyone could go more into detail about the proof.